# Why is $\cos(x)-i\sin(x) = \cos(-x)+i\sin(-x)=\operatorname*{cis}(-x)$?

Tags: complex-numbers

I do not understand why:
$$\cos(x)-i\sin(x) = \cos(-x)+i\sin(-x)$$

The last step i understand. (It is one of the solutions of a quadratic equation if it matters)

Comment: Because $\cos x$ is an even function, i.e., $f(x)=f(-x)$ is the definition for such a function.  (And also, $\sin -x=-\sin x$, since $\sin x$ is an odd function.)

Comment: what is this $sen(x)$?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Yes, sorry i forgot sen is not used in english, and thanks for the mathjax tutorial

Comment: @samjoe

$sen(x)$ is the way the Spanish write $\sin(x)$ because Sine in Spanish is **Seno**. So it is abbreviated to $sen(x)$ instead of $\sin(x)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is so, because

$$\cos (-x)=\cos (x)$$

And, $$\sin (-x)=-\sin (x) $$

Answer (score 1):

Because $\cos$ is even and $\sin$ is odd. In detail, it's because $$\cos(z)=\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}$$ and $$\sin(z)=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}.$$